# UNIX Ruby scripts on startup

Tags: ruby, unix, startup

I have three different scripts that I'd like to run on startup - currently I'm running them via:

```
nohup ruby script1.rb & disown
```

I can't seem to find how to run each of these scripts on startup, i.e. if the server happens to reboot.

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/gem
```

Distribution: Debian

Comment: google for `rc.local`. If your running `systemd` instead of `sysV` take a look at https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/26898/what-is-the-auto-start-file-like-rclocal/

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the shebang line to your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and them make you script executable

```
chmod +x great_script.rb
```

and then use it with full path, like this

```
/home/user/bin/great_script.rb
```

Also you could add your scripts folders to path:

```
export PATH=/home/user/bin:$PATH
```

Since you don't mention your distribuition, you need to check how can you add a script to the startup system manager, although following what I've posted you are able to run Ruby scripts like any regular bash script.

**UPDATE**

In debian, according to the [documentation](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian)

1. copy your file to `/etc/init.d/`
2. as root run: `update-rc.d great_script.rb defaults`

Comment: Thanks - and what would the startup configuration script be? ruby exec /path/to/script.rb?

Comment: how does this allow for the script to be ran on system startup?

Comment: I seem to be missing a stage - from what I've read there should be a script in /etc/init.d which incurs the bash script, is this correct?